# RewriteRules in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code in **.htaceess** :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule aa/(.+)  $1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule .+  index.php?username=$0 [L,QSA]
```

index.php content:

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
?>
```

and this is structure of files:

```
root
|
|_____css
|      |____ style.css
|
|_____ .htaccess
|_____ index.php
```

I want when type **http://domain/aa/css/style.css** redirects to **/css/style.css**
and for every other urls that me type ie: **http://domain/test** redirects to **/index.php?username=test**

now when I type **http://domain/test** its work good. but when I type **http://domain/aa/css/style.css** instead of **style.css** browser shows me this:

```
array(1) { ["username"]=> string(13) "css/style.css" }
```

now how change **.htaccess** to every thing works right ?

Comment: add RewriteCond before the second rewrite rule : RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .+  index.php?username=$0 [L,QSA]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use: (see comments below)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule aa/(.+) $1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/aa/ [NC]
RewriteRule .+ index.php?username=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: for now I want when user goes to `http://domain/css/style.css` even if that directory and file exists **htaccess** rewrites it to `http://domain/index.php?username=css/style.css` and only if went to `http://domain/aa/css/style.css` rewrites it to `http://domain/css/style.css` . now guide me please.

Comment: ok I removed that two rewritecond statements but this time when I go to `http://domain/aa/css/style.css` after match in first rewriterule statement , **[L] switch** don stop rewriting and output sends to second rewriterule and final output url is `http://domain/index.php?username=css/style.css` . but why ??

Comment: ok I changed it and worked right thanx. but now I want to know so for what is [L] flag . in first rewriterule statement after matching, [L] flag must stops rewriting process. but didnt do this ! why ?

Comment: No `L` doesn't stop below rules. It only stops current rule.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70115/discussion-between-saeid-and-anubhava).

Comment: Sorry just got back so couldn't join chat. Please don't add any more question to this thread and start a new one if you further issues.